# Wordpress: set up in subdir not run wp permalink?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I am Using its digital vps & nginx

Before, installing wp have abc.com format

and i change to (new site, new code): abc.com/home

but the site does not run home Permalink and error:
abc.com/home/page-page-link:

No input file specified.

Through counseling to help you with, please.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible way to solve your problem
1) Redirection in .htaccess
2) change the links in database file 
please send me your db file if possible

Thanks